# How to code an expandable pane/panel/card

Tags: java, expandable

I added an image below to show what i am trying to achieve. I've seen similar implementations of this else where but isn't sure what it's called.

What it will do is when a box/panel/card on the left is clicked, a detailed panel on the right will be displayed, showing very detailed information. If a user simply wants to see a little more, an arrow or a "show more" hyper link will expand the panel/card to display more information.

[image]

I'm wondering if some sort of java plugin is already in existence which i can modify and utilize to fit my needs, instead of coding the entire thing from scratch.

If anyone has any idea of this, i would love to hear more! Thanks in advance!